# Wordpress CORS - share fonts

Tags: php, css

I have a wordpress site on one domain and a other site on a other domain in the other domain I want to include the css-file from the wordpress site - this works fine. In this css-file i import fonts with the absolute url to the font (hosted on the same server as the wordpress-site is running) but the font gets blocked.

I already tryed to set header in php... on top of header.php:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>
```

but it still gets blocked.
What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That PHP code will only work for URLs on which it is invoked. It won't be for static files.

You can either:

- Use the URL of a PHP script which sets the header, reads the file, outputs the apropriate content-type header, then outputs the contents of the file *or*
- Set the headers in the configuration of your HTTP server (how you do that will depend on which HTTP server you use, consult its manual for setting HTTP headers).